# Displaying images from directory in ruby on rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, erb

I am developing simple web application in ruby on rails 3, where users can upload images and uploaded all images has to be displayed.
Successfully i uploaded images into folder(photos) which is located in public and stored their url path in database.I am getting problem in displaying images.

**image.html.erb**

```
<% @photo.each do |photo| %>
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <td><img src = "#{photo.url}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<%end%>
```

**in photos controller**

```
def image
  @photo = Photo.all
end
```

when iam giving path(photos/pic1.jpg) the loop has been working but it displaying only one image, if iam using photo.url it has been not displaying any image.

Answer (score 1):

To render some variable value into erb template you should use `<%= ... %>` instead of regular string interpolation `#{...}`. In your case you can do:

```
<img src = "<%= photo.url %>" />
```

Or, better, you can use [`image_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) helper:

```
<%= image_tag photo.url %>
```